# Download using tornado.httpclient — Non-blocking Python

Tags: python, callback, tornado

```
def handle_request(param1,param2):
    if response.error:
        print "Error:", response.error
    else:
        print response.body
        print param1
        print param2


param1
param2
http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
http_client.fetch("http://www.google.com/", handle_request)
```

I need to pass the param1 and param2 to the handle_request

Answer (score 2):

Use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
import functools

# handle_response will be called with three arguments:
# first the ones from the partial, and then the response
def handle_response(param1, param2, response): pass

http_client.fetch("http://www.google.com",
    functools.partial(handle_request, param1, param2))
```

Comment: Thanks @Ben Darnell you save my day :)